# I need to create one field on OpportunityContactRole

Tags: custom-field, configuration

Please suggest how I can create a custom field on `OpportunityContactrole`.
I am not able to find the Object.

Comment: maybe you can let us know why do you need custom field in OpportunityContactRole.who knows there any other workaround for that.

Answer (score 0):

That object is just a many-to-many relationship between Opportunity and Contact. Unfortunately, I don't believe Salesforce allows us to add new fields to `OpportunityContactRole` ([source](http://sfdcsrini.blogspot.com/2014/04/what-is-opportunity-contact-role.html)).

As this may well be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), maybe try expanding your question to outline what you're trying to achieve. There's probably a better way of doing it!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way of adding Custom field in `OpportunityContactRole`. There is an Idea that is already been raised in Salesforce community find the [link](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000hi0oAAA).

Comment: [Winter 20, LEX](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_sales_opportunity_contact_roles_customize.htm)  now allows custom fields to be added to OpportunityContactRole

Comment: Thanks @cropredy for the update.